# Localhost windows XAMPP not found 404

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I cannot access to http://localhost, in my browser, or even to http://localhost/dashboard/index.php.

I have already runned apache, and no port block issue.
Just that i received, object not found which is quite strange to be seen.
This happened on apache/2.4.23 (win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13

I cannot access the directory inside htdocs, which i suspect that my serverRoot does not point to the htdocs.

```
ServerRoot "C:\xampp\apache"
```

Is this the correct server root?

I tried 
    ServerRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
but once i tried that, i cannot even run apache.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: How did you install your XAMPP? Any screenshot of your 404 pages?

Comment: I will provide it soon 
@nyedidikeke

I installed it from the site

Comment: This clearly shows your XAMPP is up and working. Try just `localhost/`; what do you get? Also: you've not answered my question on how you've installed your XAMPP! In case you've made any extra configurations, do share as well.

Comment: I get the same error.
I went to the https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html to download the xampp @nyedidikeke

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`; what do you get?